# Rectifying browser scaling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, hdpi

When designing a website, the website looks proper on all displays and browsers. However, when moving towards HDPI displays (above the resolution of 1920x1080), chrome and Firefox scale the content by default. This makes text, that looks correct on Microsoft Edge, very big. I could change my browser settings but the not everyone would.

I would like to know how to have the text scale properly and look the right size on HDPI displays.

Answer (score 0):

*Use Media Queries*

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1080px)
    {
      body or yourdiv element
      {
        font:<size>px/em/cm;
      }
    }
```

This Link might help as well. [Optimize for Displays](https://css-tricks.com/optimizing-large-scale-displays/)